# I have installed Mongodb recently in my Ubuntu using terminal as per the guidlines and i am unable to use mongo shell?

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, mongoose, terminal

This is the problem coming when i am opening the mongo shell
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZypxV.png

Comment: You get an 'operation not permitted' error. Can you try with super user?
And the command to use the mongo **shell** is `mongo`, not `mongod`.

Comment: Till where i know to use mongo shell we need to use mongod command before.But still the problem is not solved yet

Comment: Please, do NOT use images for textual information. Instead, copy the error log in the terminal and **paste** it to the question post as *text*. The pasted could be formatted as a code, with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button. See also [ask].